# Checking whether scala set intersection is empty

Tags: scala, set, scala-collections

Is there a recommended way to check whether two scala collection `Set`s have a non-empty intersection? There is of course the obvious

```
set1.intersect(set2).isEmpty
```

But that actually constructs the intersection set first, unless I am mistaken. Is there a better/faster way?

Answer (score 3):

The idiomatic way is to use .intersect() or .diff() but both ways build new collection internally.

Fastest ways are:

- Manually iterate over first set until match in the second
- Use probabilistic Bloom Filter that take some time to construct it but can compare two sets (even very huge) very fast (occasionally may give false positives)

Answer (score 3):

I'd recommend this:

```
set1.exists(set2.contains)
```

Not nearly as readable as "set1.intersectionNonEmpty(set2)", but you could read it as "In **set1**, there *exists* some element that **set2** *contains*".